# Can't access WCF service hosted on IIS remotely but can access it locally

Tags: wcf, iis

I have deployed a WCF service that use HTTP binding on IIS 7.5.
When logged on the web server I'm able to browse to the svc file:
"http://localhost:8200/MyService.svc"

But when I do it from a remote machine it is not available:
"http://11.22.33.44:8200//MyService.svc"

Any idea?

Comment: When you say not available, what error are you getting? When you try http://11.22.33.44:8200//MyService.svc?wsdl do you see wsdl file?

Comment: Can you provide more detail please (e.g. what does your web.config look like and what is the exact error message you are getting when calling the service remotely)?

Comment: I'm getting Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage when accessing remotly. When on the server I see the wsdl

Comment: Having the same problem connection gets time out but on server i can see my wcf service also i can browse directory on remote but when i click on svc file it gets time out any solution?

Comment: Also take a look at ***http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202255/cannot-access-wcf-service-remotely***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Firewall is off, or that it allows connections to port 8200

Comment: Created a new inbound rule on the Firewall for port 8200 and the service is now accessible remotely. Thanks