# Cannot access WCF service remotely

Tags: wcf, web-services

**BACKGROUND**

We have a **WCF web service** hosted in a **Windows Service** running with the **basicHttpBinding**.

**PROBLEM**

Browsing to the service URL on the local machine works fine, but trying to browse using the external IP address (either remotely or EVEN locally) does not work. Example:

`http://localhost:8000/booking.svc` (OK)

`http://<external-IP>:8000/booking.svc` (Not OK)

**APP.CONFIG**

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceBehavior" name="HotelManagementSystem.ServiceHost.BookingService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HotelManagementSystem.ServiceHost.IBookingService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/booking.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Firewall? Did you add exception to port 8000 in the server?

Comment: In addition to firewall, does adding an entry for `baseAddress="http://external-ip:8000/booking.svc` allow you to connect? (I've had great luck with using `useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress`)

Comment: @Anuraj, I have been told by the customer that port 8000 has been opened

Comment: @Matt - are you able to telnet to port 8000?  Also, can you (or the customer) check the event viewer to see if anything is logged in there?

Comment: @BradChristie, the `useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress` thing worked briliantly. Thank you! If you add as answer, I will happily mark that as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816894.aspx)

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This will allow the service to insert the URI you used to access the service in to the metadata so the wsdl aligns. Sometimes you'll go to access `http://1.2.3.4/service.svc` but the metadata will reference `http://localhost`. Locally that's fine, but remotely that makes grabbing the endpoint information impossible. Instead, now all those `localhost` references will use `1.2.3.4` instead.

Comment: Neat trick - I'll have to pass this on to my teammates.  Wasn't my question, but a quite useful answer.