# WCF Service public-facing

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, wcf, iis

I'm currently trying to "deploy" a WCF service I've created and am consuming with a WPF app.
At the moment, I am running it on localhost, and consuming it fine, but when I try and access it from the internal IP Address (192.168.0.xxx:59999), I get invalid hostname. I've done some googling and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Basically I want it so that any computer on the xxx path can consume the service. How would I go about setting that up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to access a web service from an external client, you need to make sure you have an addressable IP (either the same network or an internet address) and a network path (firewall rules allow routing).  Therefore, the first thing you want to verify, is that your Windows firewall is allowing your target IP address to access port 59999.

Comment: I have already tried adding incoming firewall rules for :59999. Still no luck.

Comment: Maybe try setting the useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress value.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202255/cannot-access-wcf-service-remotely